# iphone - String does not keep its value

Tags: ios, string, null, syntax-error

The string `selectedSong` does not keep its value when I, in my storyboard switch to another ViewController. Even though all my viewcontroller are connected to the ViewController classes.
I've done like this

First View:

```
- (IBAction)selectTheSong {
    selectedSong = @"test";
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedSong);
}
```

and there it returns the value `test` in the log.

Second View:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedSong);


if (audioPlayer == nil) {


NSString* soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedSong ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];


NSError *error = nil;

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];



[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

and this time it returns `(null)` in the log.

Is the string not set up properly? I tried making it a property etc. but that didn't work.
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set the string up as a property with the `strong` retain type in your class interface.

eg.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;
```

Also, always access that string instance using the `self` keyword to ensure the synthesized accessor methods are being called.

i.e.

```
self.myString = @"Hello!";
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I was looking for although I haven't tested it yet since I went with doing NSUserDefaults. I know that is wrong but keeping one string won't make any harm, right? Should I stick with what I have or use your idea?

Comment: I would use a property, unless you wish to retain the state of the string even after your app is closed. Unwise unless necessary, no point wasting the space on the user's iPhone even if it is only a string. Plus, properties are kind of a cornerstone in Objective-C development and by learning the basics of their operation you will be surprised at how much more you will understand, at least I was when I first started iOS. They sort of revealed to me the whole notion of OOP, accessor methods and memory management when I first started out in software development.

Answer (score 0):

Using a property is the way to go. How did you pass the value of the string from one ViewController to the other? You should do that in the `prepareForSegue:` method.